# Запятая в сложносочиненом предложении

Tags: синтаксис, запятые, ссп

**День умирал и люди тоже.**

Нужна ли запятая? Какое это предложение: сложносочиненное или простое с однородными членами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**День умирал, и люди тоже (умирали).**

Сложносочиненное предложение, второе предложение неполное, запятая ставится, общих элементов нет.

В  устной речи делается пауза, харктерная для сложного предложения.